# Insert fails with 1064 (42000) syntax error

Tags: python, sql, mysql

Table with columns `order_id`, `op_id`, `file` and `imgs` I'm using following function to insert data in it:

```
def blocks_files(self, db, order_id, op_id, file_ids, images):
    """Filling the blocks_files table."""
    files_list = []
    for file in file_ids:
        if images.__contains__(file):
            img = []
            img.extend(images[file])
            files_list.append((order_id, op_id, file, str(img)))
    try:
        logging.debug(
            "Inserting data in blocks_files."
        )
        cursor = db.cursor()
        query = (
            f"INSERT INTO {self.FILES_TABLE}"
            f"(order_id, op_id, file_id, imgs)"
            f"VALUES {(', '.join(map(str, files_list)))};"
        )
        cursor.execute(query)
        db.commit()
        cursor.close()
        logging.debug(
            "Data inserted successfully!"
        )
    except connector.Error as err:
        logging.error(err)
```

In logs I have the following line:

> ERROR - 2023-07-18 10:40:17,131 - root - 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

I found `Messages that say ...near '' at line...` means the end of command was encountered unexpectedly (something else should appear before the command ends) but I don't know how to fix this. I tried to insert manually:

```
query = (
                f"INSERT INTO {self.FILES_TABLE}"
                f"(order_id, op_id, file_id, imgs)"
                f"VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)"
            )
            values = (order_id, op_id, 111111, "222222, 333333")
            cursor.execute(query, values)
```

It successfully executes with no errors and all data is in place.

Comment: The only thing I notice that should be different between the two is that `f"VALUES {(', '.join(map(str, files_list)))};"` will come out to something like `VALUES val1, val2, val3, val4` and will miss out the brackets around the comma separated values which you manual query has. I'm not too familiar with SQL, is this the kind of thing that could make it think the query ended early?

Comment: @Cmd858 It happened that I misread the situation. The `if` part was just not working properly, therefore the code provided nothing to insert and error was raised

Answer (score 1):

Well, the problem was in the `if` part, it didn't correctly check for the keys. If somehow someones interested this worked for me:

```
files_list = []
keys = list(images.keys())
for file in file_ids:
    if str(file) in keys:
        img = list()
        img.append(images[str(file)])
        files_list.append((order_id, op_id, file, str(img)))
```